# How to condense the text inside "minted" environment?

Tags: minted

I have a piece of text inside `minted` environment and it is too wide. I'm trying to find  a way to condense it. Just this particular piece of text, not all texts in the entire document.

Comment: `{\small\begin{minted}.....\end{minted}}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this doesn't change the spacing between letters, only makes letters smaller

Comment: ? normally minted is using a monospace font naturally spaced there is no space added between letters

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm looking for a negative spacing then, to make the text more "condensed"

Comment: you could choose a more condensed font, minted isn't adding space at all there it is just typesetting `hello world` so adding negative space between each letter would require major rewrites probably (and would in general cause letters to overprint)

Comment: If you use lualatex you can use some condensed programmer fonts, like iosevka: https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka (there should be lot of questions here about how to change font in minted etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than “condense”, I'd use a smaller font size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{latex}
This is \LaTeX\ code in standard size
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}[fontsize=\small]{latex}
This is \LaTeX\ code in smaller size
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}[fontfamily=lmtt,fontseries=lc]{latex}
This is \LaTeX\ code in condensed type
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Using a condensed font is possible, as you see, but with severe limitations.

[image]